# What could be causing this must understand element

Tags: wcf, soap-client

I have just imported the wsdl of a java web service into a .net WCF client project.

When I run the client it fails.

To analyse the error I logged the soap request and sent it from a SOAP UI project. I get the following error:

```
  <soapenv:Fault xmlns:axis2ns35="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
     <soapenv:Code>
        <soapenv:Value>axis2ns35:MustUnderstand</soapenv:Value>
     </soapenv:Code>
     <soapenv:Reason>
        <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">Must Understand check failed for headers: {http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none}Action</soapenv:Text>
     </soapenv:Reason>
     <soapenv:Detail/>
  </soapenv:Fault>
```

This is being caused by the following line in the SOAP request:

```
  <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none"/>
```

Question is, why is WCF generating this element?

Comment: Are you able to post the contract or more details about the web service? It seems odd that a service would mark an action header with 'must understand' and then not understand it, which makes me suspect its the client that must understand something. Please post any more contract details you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF should never send this element ({http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none}Action). It sometimes appears internally in WCF message logs but never sent out. Most probably this header appears in the contract in some way. Please publish your binding, and also search in your proxy code if this element appears there directly.